# Blazor aync method doesn't fully execute

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor

doing a task and I'm stuck. My code doesn't fully go through. I believe there is a problemn with await, async stuff.

My problem: in @foreach method I call a method "loadEach" and I it checks if that current order line must be colored orange. but the problem is that in the middle on loadEach method (after works api call) it instantly get's called again with another order.Id value and loadEach method never fully goes through. What can I do, that blazor would wait till the loadEach method is fully done and then go and build the table?

```
                @foreach (var order in sortedOrders)
                {
                    loadEach(order.Id).ConfigureAwait(true);

                    <tr style="background-color:@(hasPausedOperation == true ? "#ebc14d" : "")" @onclick="@(() => Selected(order.Id))">
                        @*<td @onclick="@(() => Selected(order.Id))">@order.WorkCenterValue</td>*@
                        <td>@order.OrderNumber</td>
                        <td>@order.Customer</td>
                        <td>@order.ExpectedStartDateTime?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")</td>
                        <td>@order.EndDateTime?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")</td>
                        <td>@order.ExternalWorker</td>
                        @*<td @onclick="@(() => Selected(order.Id))">@order.Priority</td>*@
                    </tr>
                    @if (orderId != null && orderId == order.Id)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5">
                                <Logging orderId="order.Id" workCenter="workCenter"></Logging>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }

                    hasPausedOperation = false;
                }
```

```
protected async Task loadEach(int orderId)
    {
        if (orderId != 0)
        {
            works = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WorksListModel>($"Works?orderId={orderId}");

            foreach (var work in works.Works)
            {
                if ((work.EndDateTime == null && work.StartDateTime != null && canStart && work.WorkLogEndDateTime != null))
                {
                    hasPausedOperation = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And is there any difference between those 2 razor snippets?  Explain that or delete one.

Comment: I posted the whole loadeach method in the end of the page. Or I need to post something more that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I now fixed the post. Maybe it's cleaner now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to need that information for each row.

The most efficient solution would be to let the Server figure this out, the total execution time would be much lower that way. hasPausedOperation can be a property of the WorkItem  Dto/ViewModel.

If you do want it delayed like this, storing the information in a shared variable is not the best way. And Blazor does not support async code in the razor  section.

So, option a:

```
 var hasPausedOperation = loadEach(order.Id); // no await
```

but this requires a `bool loadEach(int orderId)`, no async, no Task. You will have to call .Result on the HttpClient call.

the better option b, create a component for the row:

```
@foreach (var order in sortedOrders)
{
   <OrderRow Order="@order" />
}
```

in the `OrderRow` component you have an async OnInitializedAsync() where you can handle this properly.

You can have a component for a `<tr>` .